# desktop pc crashed on ubuntu 20.04 LTS release upgrade from 19.10

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, uefi, 19.10, 20.04

Have a Dell laptop pc dual booting windows 10 pro and Ubuntu 19.10. It was working fine for past few months. I tried to do a release upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The upgeade was happening smoothly till almost the end when I got the message "OOPs Something Went Wrong".

I tried rebooting. The grub menu comes up but gives the same message when trying to boot Ubuntu.

It is booting fine in Windows 10

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: There is known issue (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1872902) however this isn't the place to discuss, nor look if your issue is that or something different. Sites and methods (IRC) that support #ubuntu+1 would be more appropriate, or referring to bug reports (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: @guiverc, it's already 23rd April in several countries.

Comment: I'm in Australia so I'm very well aware of that, but in my local time the release will likely occur 24-April or the Friday morning (releases are always thursday UTC time).  The last re-spin hasn't even completed; let alone testing of it... and the eventual release. It's still *focal fossa* and development.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka The date is not relevant but the actual release.

Comment: @guiverc We know that but newcomers don't know that.

Comment: @pLumo, am I being too nice?

Comment: if it fails to boot up correctly then boot up into the Recovery menu where you can run as root to fix packages or any other issue